# Cucumber - Could not find DataTableType.entry in my TypeRegistryConfigurer class

Tags: datatable, cucumber

I am currently using Cucumber and I am trying to use the TypeRegistryConfigurer to automatically transform the dataTable to my class. I am using the following code in my TypeRegistryConfiguration:

```java
    import static java.util.Locale.ENGLISH;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import my.company.decision.calculator.service.domain.CalculationRequest;
    import my.company.decision.calculator.service.domain.CalculationResponse;
    import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistry;
    import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistryConfigurer;
    import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableType;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import java.util.Locale;

    public class CalculationApiTypeRegistryConfiguration implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {
        @Override
        public Locale locale() {
            return Locale.ENGLISH;
        }

        @Override
        public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
            typeRegistry.defineDataTableType(DataTableType.entry(Example.class));
        }
    }
```

However I am getting the error message:

> Cannot find method DataTableType.entry.

My gradle dependencies are the following:

```
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '5.0.0'
testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '5.0.0'
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cucumber v5 has an annotation based configuration that will let you do this:

```
package io.cucumber.examples.java;

import io.cucumber.java.DataTableType;
import java.util.Map;

public class ShoppingSteps {

    @DataTableType
    public Grocery defineGrocery(Map<String, String> entry) {
        return new Grocery(entry.get("name"), Integer.parse(entry.get("price")));
    }
```

You can also pass the `entry` to a mapper like Jackson to do the conversion for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately that does not fully fill my requirements. I want to have an automated mapping, from the DataTable input to my object. Do you know how this is made in Cucumber version 5?

Comment: Pass the entry to Jackson. Or register a default transformer that uses Jackson once 

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/release-notes/v5.0.0.md#default-transformer

Answer (score 0):

I used following Cucumber versions and it worked:

```
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '4.8.1'
testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '4.8.1'
```